# How to search for images of compounds?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure on what SE I should ask this question, so the safest bet I can make is this one. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to find the actual picture of compounds when I search for them. For example, just now I wanted to search for how interstitial compounds look in real life but all I am getting are structural images of the same. So is there any website or a specific phrase that can get me to results?

Comment: Try adding “micrograph” or afm or scanning to your search terms.

Comment: @Karsten I meant macroscopic images, like when searching for coal getting this https://search.brave.com/images?origin=search&q=coal and not this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Scanning-electron-microscope-micrograph-of-activated-carbon_fig2_334747278

Comment: Most compounds have pretty boring appearance that can be summarized in a couple of words like "red powder" or "colorless viscous liquid", and those who post crystal structures sure do provide this information, too. It's just that the set of numerical properties (atomic coordinates, physical properties) is much more interesting and objective than a photo: the captured appearance depends on scene (ambient conditions), illumination, camera settings, fineness of the substance (morphology) and many other factors at the same time conveying very little practical information.